# How do I prevent two box elements from overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with positioning box elements.  More specifically, keeping two box elements from overlapping.  I attached the image of my page to show you what I mean and my code:

Overlap problem:

[image: overlap problem]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>TMNT - Rancid Tomatoes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="movie.css">

   <meta charset="utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
 <img class="width" src="images/rancidbanner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes">
 </div>

 <h1>TMNT (2015)</h1>

    <!---block one--->
    <div class="div1">

        <!---block two--->
        <div class="div2">
        <img class="tLeft" src="images/rottenlarge.png" alt="Rotten" />          <strong>33%</strong>
        </div>

    <!---block three--->
    <div class="div3">
    <img class="tRight" src="images/overview.png" alt="general overview" />
    </div>

    <!---box four--->
    <div class="div4">
           <p>HEllo relkgnaldfkgnadlgsknasdlkgnasldkgnaslkdgnasldkn   sjdnaslkdjfnaslkdjfn sdgnaslkjgnlaskjgdn
        </p>
      </div>
     </div>


</html>


 body{
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
}

 h1{
    text-shadow: 2px 3px gray;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
  }

 img.width{
    width: 100%;
 }

img.tLeft {
    float: left;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-right: 3em;
 }

img.tRight {
     float: right;
 }


.div1 {
position: relative;
width: 900px;
height: 700px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 20px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #A8A8A8;
background-color: #4dffa6;
overflow: hidden;
 }

 .div2 {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid red;
overflow: hidden;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.div3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
   height: auto;
   border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
 }

.div4 {
    position: absolute;
width: auto;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid blue;
background-color: lightgray;
overflow: hidden;
left: 0;
 }

strong{
    font-size: 70px;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: never use position until you really need it. you can remove position and give two box float one of them right and one of theme left and

Comment: Flexbox is also a good option @mkafiyan

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh yes he can use it too

Answer (score 0):

never use position until you really need it
just change you coode and remove your position, also you give overflow-hidden with height:auto????? when you give height auto it mean that until you have data or item in your div height automatically will be bigger and bigger. then overflow doesn't mean.

```
.div4{
height:auto;
width:300px;
float:left;
border: 1px solid blue;
background-color: lightgray;

}
.div3{
float:right;
width:300px;
height:auto;
border: 1px solid red;
overflow: hidden;
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

if you give width auto this problem happening. give width to your div and also float.

Comment: @ChristianSoto if my way can solve your problem just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> Flex Box

```
<div class='main-container'>

<!-- Container for text -->
<div class='first-container'>
 <p>Hello relkgnaldfkgnadlgsknasdlkgnasldkgnaslkdgnasldknsjdnaslkdjfnaslkdjf</p>
</div>

<!-- Container for image -->
<div class='second-container'>
<img src='' alt='general overview' />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code -

```
.main-container{
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

This will keep the two containers separate.
Simple as that.

> Additionally you can apply style as per your need.